# How to use a Graph Convolutional Network model (node classification) in practice?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, classification, graph-theory

I have built a GCN model for a binary node classification on a custom Twitter followers graph. I'm having good enough results and I'd like to know how I can use this model in practice.

Can I directly feed to it new unseen graph data and get predictions ? I'm confused because of the way node embeddings are generated, since they are updated during the training phase. Do I have to do some training every time I use a new graph ?